# Possible memory leak in URLRead? (MMA v11.3)

Tags: memory, web-access

I was writing a API with a lot of http requests, when I noticed Mathematica was slowly using more and more memory, and after some debugging I think the culprit is `URLRead`.

The following code should reproduce the problem,

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

mem = N@MemoryInUse[];
Do[URLRead["http://wolfram.com", {"StatusCode", "Headers"}];, {i,100}];
N@MemoryInUse[] - mem
```

> 215 488.

While a similar block of code with `RandomReal` instead produces no significant increase of memory usage. Moreover, `ClearSystemCache` will only reduce the memory after the first run on a fresh kernel.

---

The questions then: Can anybody reproduce these results? Is this expected behaviour? And more importantly, since I plan to continuously run my API, **is there a way to reclaim this memory?**

---

**Tested on MMA 11.3.0.0 on macOS 10.13.3**

Comment: But it is `0.2 MB`, is it significant?

Comment: @Kuba In the case of my API this amounts to about `0.7 MB` per 5 minutes, and since I plan to continuously run the code for days, this will become significant.

Comment: I can also see an average *10.7 kbytes* per call to `URLRead`, growing linearly. Mma 11.3.0  Win7 64. Using a local server and `Table[
 {
  Do[URLRead[url, {"StatusCode", "Headers"}];, {i, 10}];
  10 k,
  N@MemoryInUse[]
  },
 {k, 0, 20}
 ]`

Comment: I checked on 12.0 development build I currently work on, and, at least on Mac OS, I don't have this issue. So hopefully it has been fixed already.

Comment: If I run the code on Mac OS 10.15.6
MMA 12.1.1.0 I get 1.59103x10^7
So the problem is still there and seems even worse?